Is the field of clopen sets of a Stonean space a complete field of sets
Let $A$ be a complete Boolean algebra and $S(A)$ its Stone space (hence $S(A)$ is compact, Hausdorff, and extremally disconnected, i.e. the closure of every open set in $S(A)$ is open). Then, by the Stone representation theorem, $A$ is isomorphic to $Clop(S(A))$, which is thus an example of a field of sets which is a complete Boolean algebra. Is $Clop(S(A))$ also an example of a complete field of sets? I think, yes, because $S(A)$ is extremally disconnected. Could somebody please confirm?

Let $A = \mathcal{P}(\omega)$. For each $n\in \omega$, let $U_n$ be the principal ultrafilter generated by $n$. Then the singleton set $\{U_n\}$ is clopen. But $\bigcup_{n\in \omega} \{U_n\} = \{U_n\mid n\in \omega\}$ is not clopen. Indeed, the closure of this set is $S(A)$. So $\mathrm{Clop}(S(A))$ is not a complete field of sets.

Thank you for your answer. I understand that your set $\bigcup_{n\in\omega}U_n$ is open but not closed. But isn't it the point of extremal disconnectedness to close off that set and to take it as open so that it is clopen?

@Hugh What is your definition of "complete field of sets"?

For me, a "complete" field of sets is a field which is closed under arbitrary infinite unions (not only countable)

As it happens, I also just found that post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948778/sigma-space-to-complete-space?rq=1 where Henno Brandsma claims that the algebra of clopen sets of an extremally disconnected (Stone) space is complete. Sorry, I don't want to sound difficult or contentious, I just want to understand

@Hugh Ok, great, so we agree on the definition. And I gave you a family of clopen sets whose union is not clopen. Thus the field of clopen sets is not a complete field of sets. What's the confusion?

@Hugh In the linked post, Henno Brandsma doesn't say anything about complete fields of sets. What he says is that the algebra of clopen sets of an externally disconnected space is complete (as a Boolean algebra). One has to keep in mind the subtle distinction between a complete Boolean algebra (every family of elements has a least upper bound) and a complete field of sets (where the least upper bond is required to be the actual union). I didn't mention the distinction because I thought it was clear to you - you say the clopen algebra is a complete BA and ask if it's a complete field of sets.
